# set a variable in the global namespace for jest tests

Tags: jestjs

My code uses global `google.maps` namespace. In dev/prod it is provided by the google maps library import. In tests, I have to stub it, but I cannot put it on the global object.

Things I've tried:

```
global.google = { 
  maps: {...
  }
}
```

```
(window as any).google = { 
  maps: {...
  }
}
```

I've tried putting it in beforeEach, and in the test itself. Every time I get the

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by putting

```
declare var google: any;
```

in the file that uses the google libs (not the .spec.ts test file). Before it was importing google from another file which was also declaring. No idea why this is so. I'll raise an issue with jest.